# Spring boot integration test fails because of missing rabbit factory

Tags: java, testing, rabbitmq, integration-testing, amqp

I have an application that uses rabbitmq, and consumes message. I want to write an integration test to check all the features.My config is below:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.mysite.domaintools", "com.mysite.core",
        "com.mysite.database.repository"})
@EntityScan("com.mysite.database.domain")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mysite.database.repository.mongo"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mysite.database.repository") @EnableRabbit
public class DomaintoolsApplication {

    private static final String topicExchangeName = "mysite";

    private static final String queueName = Queues.DOMAINTOOLS.getName();


    @Bean Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
    }

    @Bean Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("domaintools.key.#");
    }

    @Bean SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(DomainToolsRabbitReceiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DomaintoolsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Everything is fine when I run my application, but when I try to run the folowing test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
//@SpringBootTest
public class DomainToolsWorkerIT {

    @Autowired
    private DomainRepository domainRepository;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

I get exception that rabbit connection factory was not found! But I am not supposed to init it because spring boot should do it. It says that no candidates found for ConnectionFactory bean, expected at least one. How may I write test in app that uses rabbitmq?

Comment: maybe your need to add @EnableRabbit to your config and use that config in your test

Answer (score -2):

You need to annotate your test class with EnableRabbit :

and add RabbitTemplate with it's ConnectionFactory using different mock object:

mock factory, connection and channel.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = DomaintoolsApplication.class)
@EnableRabbit
public class DomainToolsWorkerIT {

    @Autowired
    private DomainRepository domainRepository;

         /**
         * Create test rabbit template to not load a real rabbitMQ instance.
         *
         * @return rabbit template.
         */
        @Bean
        public RabbitTemplate template() {
            return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        }

        /**
         * Connection factory mock to create rabbit template.
         *
         * @return connection factory mock.
         */
        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            ConnectionFactory factory = mock(ConnectionFactory.class);
            Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
            Channel channel = mock(Channel.class);
            doReturn(connection).when(factory).createConnection();
            doReturn(channel).when(connection).createChannel(anyBoolean());
            doReturn(true).when(channel).isOpen();
            return factory;
        }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this config gives error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.eye4fraud.domaintools.DomainToolsWorkerIT]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=class org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper)]

Comment: Also can you share example with imports? I can't find Channel class with createchannel method

Comment: Also I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Test classes cannot include @Bean methods

Comment: Also after moving beans to config bean: Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Connection$MockitoMock$1579221884 cannot be returned by createConnection()
createConnection() should return Connection